# How can I go about learning aerospace/space engineering Pre-College?

Tags: aerospace-engineering

I am 16 years old and have grown a real interest in engineering and just rockets in general, I am unsure of how I can start learning about it though. I am obviously not yet eligible for college but I don't just wanna sit around waiting till then to start learning...Is there any sites or videos or book that one would recommend to get my start in engineering early?

Comment: Libraries have books on engineering although some libraries are better than others - usually because they are close to or part of universities associated with engineering companies. Many books are also available online as pdf and are free. Do a search and enjoy reading.

Comment: get ahead on math, physics, and possibly computer programming (esp. python and matlab, maybe mathematica - but math first!). If you can skip out of the 1st year stuff with advanced pre college ctedits, you will do more interesting things. Or alternatively can upgrade to the honors or hard science versions of the same classes.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get involved with a model rocketry club, and/or a radio-controlled model airplane club. If you have plenty of money, you can also enroll in ground school & flight training at a local airport. The money part is important because aircraft fly because of 1) money, and 2) the bernoulli effect.

Comment: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ has a lot of neat stuff. At work, we built tools run by www.arduino.cc (UNO and MEGA) (single board computers, www.adafruit.com makes some too) mind you they are limited, but have a great deal of IO to read multiple sensors (Hall effect for position/speed, humidity, temp), and to control motors, solenoids, mini displays, using transistors to switch higher voltage devices, and Pulse Width Modulation (duty cycle - to modulate a 5-volt signal). I also bet you'd have fun with rocketry (quick to get into).

Comment: I would also like to introduce you to Hyper Physics and Hyper Math. These sites summarize Physics and Math fairly nicely, so that you can examine some concepts and become familiar with them on your own. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hmat.html#hmath

Comment: Airplanes do not fly because of beroulli effect. how is it that they can fly upside down?

Comment: because their inverted angle of attack yields bernoulli effects.