# Any books or websites that anyone would recommend

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

I am a secondary/high school student to look into to help with mechanical engineering. I would like to do this for enrichment and as preparation for doing it at university. As well as this I am really interested in the topic and am not really sure where to start my learning properly.

Comment: see https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/44931/10902

Comment: look at a college curriculum and how the courses are structured.  then see that post ^

Comment: Anything about free body diagrams.